# Create a LoadUser controller with custom routing in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to create custom urls for my LoadUser controller. I want the url to be

> site.com/LoadUser/1.

The `LoadUserByID` route is above my default route. I keep getting the default error page

> "Error. An error occurred while processing your request."

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

My code is as follows:

RouteConfig.cs

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "LoadUserByID",
    url: "LoadUser/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "LoadUser", action = "ID", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

LoadUserController.cs

```
//
// GET: /LoadUser/[userid]

public ActionResult ID(int id)
{
    ViewBag.Message = "ID page";
    return View();
}
```

**UPDATE**

Code is fine and I'm new to MVC. I did not have a View created for LoadUser. I thought I could use the default view. Make sure to have a view created that correlates to your Controller/Action.

Comment: might i suggest webapi?

Comment: This should work. What error are you getting? Could you post some more  details? If you put a breakpoint in your controller action, does it get hit? If not which action gets invoked (if any)?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I'm using the default MVC4 web application in Visual Studio 2012. I get the generic "Error. An error occurred while processing your request." Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/xVba5do.png

Comment: I just created a new ASP.NET MVC 4 application using the default template, added a new `LoadUserController` with a controller action exactly as shown in your question, added the custom route as shown in your question and when I navigated to `LoadUser/1` everything worked perfectly fine - the controller action was hit and the view was rendered. So I guess my question is: what did you do differently than those steps?

Comment: Try debugging and and set the option to break on all CLR exceptions, sounds like something odd is happening unrelated to your route.

Comment: Ok, it looks like a View issue. Do I have to create a View specifically for the ID action? I thought I could just use the default view. `The view 'ID' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations.`

Comment: Is the `ID` view properly located in the `/Views/LoadUser/` folder?  This is the default location and if you have it somewhere else you will either need to move it or override the view engine to look in the different location.

Comment: @asymptoticFault It is now. I updated my code above.

Comment: Yep that would be the problem :P